# Split word document by regex, and then group like headings into their own objects

Tags: python, regex, docx

I have a `docx`, which I read into jupyter like so:

```
### Import libraries
import docx2txt
import os
import re
import pandas
import docx

### Read document
file_text = docx2txt.process("big_document.docx")
```

In this document, there are multiple pages with the same headers. I want to search for these headers, and then group all like headers into their own objects. In the following chunk, the first thirty pages of my document all have the same header, `EXAMPLE ONE` (it's not in a header format, just the one unique identifying string on each page that matches the other 29 pages):

```
### Loop to get appropriate sections, according to the re.findall()
for i in range(0, 30):
    match = re.findall('EXAMPLE\sONE', file_text)
    print(match[i])
```

The `re.findall()` finds every instance of `EXAMPLE ONE`, but it only returns those two words 30 times. If I sub in `re.split()`, and set the range accordingly, it returns the whole document (several hundred pages).

```
### Loop to get appropriate sections, according to the re.split()
for i in range(0, 30):
    match = re.split('EXAMPLE\sONE', file_text)
    print(match[i])

# still returns whole document, instead of just the 30 pages with the chosen header
```

How do I set the code so it only returns the pages with the appropriate headers, and only those pages? I think `re.split()` is my tool, but I can't make it work.

The document has multiple headers, going up to `EXAMPLE SEVEN`, and I was going to make a `for` loop for each, and `return` an object. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you will be able to get the matching page for a given header, since If i'm not wrong `docx` won't return an 'end-of-page' character which could allow you to specify an end to the content you want.

What you could do, however, is to use a regex like this to get all the content *before* a certain header:

```
match = re.search('^((.|\n)+)EXAMPLE\nTWO', file_text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: Another question - how would I get the text between two sections? As in everything between `EXAMPLE THREE` and `EXAMPLE TWO`, without adding in `EXAMPLE ONE`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... If you want the text between A and B, just use something like `A((.|\n)+)B`. If you need to do more with regex, you could take a look at a site like https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
from docx2python import docx2python
from docx2python.iterators import iter_paragraphs
from collections import defaultdict
import re

text = docx2python('path_to_file.docx')
groups = defaultdict(list)
for par in iter_paragraphs(text.document):
    header = re.search('EXAMPLE\s[A-Z]+', par)
    if header:
        open_group = groups[header.group()]
    open_group.append(par)
```